# i have used replace("[^-A-Za-z0-9()%.] but it throws error missing comma for ' come can i resolve this error

Tags: javascript

I have used replace `("[^-A-Za-z0-9()%.]` but it throws error missing comma for `'` (apostrophe) how can i resolve this error.

every other special character is being replaced or does not throw an error

Comment: I can see an unbalanced brace , Is '(' is part of your regex? If it is so you can try by using this ("[^-A-Za-z0-9()%.] )

Comment: Show more of the surrounding code!

Comment: Please show the complete statement or share a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Use this https://regex101.com/ to validate your regex

Comment: "+tw.local.RBDG.BranchName.replace("[^-A-Za-z0-9()%.]", " ")+"', this replaces or allows what ever i want to but when ' (apostrophe)  for eg: arun's comes it throws missing comma error

Comment: can anyone help our BPM application is throwing missing comma error when ever some one inputs an  ' (apostrophe)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex validator 
[Regex validator](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html)

also in the replace method you have to provide source string and the string you want it to replace with

Comment: "+tw.local.RBDG.BranchName.replace("[^-A-Za-z0-9()%.]", " ")+"', this works and replaces or allows what ever i want to but when ' (apostrophe) for eg: arun's comes it throws missing comma error